# displaying array

Tags: php, arrays

Good day.

Am displaying array in five columns and I need to push value to the last if values having specified key arrived at last.

```
<?php

$say = array("1","2","3","4","m"=>"5","s"=>"6","7","8","9","10","11","12");

$columns = 5;

for ($p=0; $p <count($say); $p++) {


    if ($p==0) { 
            print "<table><tr>";
    } elseif ($p%$columns == 0) { 
            print "<tr>";
    }

    print "<td>".htmlspecialchars($say[$p])."</td>";


    if (($p+1)%$columns == 0) { 
            print "</tr>";
    }
    if ($p==count($say)-1) { 
            $empty = $columns - (count($say)%$columns) ;
            if ($empty != $columns) {
                    print "<td colspan=$empty>&nbsp;</td>";
                    }
            print "</tr></table>";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

I used this code to display in five columns

Comment: i doesn't have any error. actually i don't want to display the two values at the end of each row. in that case the value before that value which is having key must pushed at end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments below, this should solve your problem:

```
<?php

// Returns TRUE is the value is non-numeric otherwise FALSE.
function is_non_numeric($value)
{
  return ! is_numeric($value);
}

// The number of columns
$columns = 5;

// The data
$data = array('1', '2', '3', '4', 'm' => '5', 's' => '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12');

// Chunk the data into rows of {$columns} columns.
$rows = array_chunk($data, $columns, TRUE);

// Output the table if there are rows.
if ( ! empty($rows) )
{
  echo '<table>';

  // Loop through each rows.
  foreach ( $rows as $row )
  {
    // Find all non-numeric keys, if any.
    $non_numeric_keys = array_filter(array_keys($row), 'is_non_numeric');

    // Loop through each non-numeric keys if one or more were found.
    if ( ! empty($non_numeric_keys) )
      foreach ( $non_numeric_keys as $offset => $non_numeric_key )
      {
        // Skip this one of the non-numeric key isn't the first or last of the row.
        if ( $offset != 0 && $offset != ( $columns - 1 ) )
          continue;

        // Remove the value with a non-numeric key from the row.
        $value = array_splice($row, $offset, 1);

        // Randomly select where the value will be re-inserted.
        $random = rand(1, ( $columns - 2 ));

        // Re-insert the value with a non-numeric key.
        array_splice($row, $random, 0, $value);
      }

    echo '<tr>';

    // Loop through each columns.
    foreach ( $row as $index => $column )
      echo '<td>' . $column . '</td>';

    // If the row doesn't have {$columns} columns add one that spans the number of missing columns.
    if ( ( $colspan = $columns - count($row) ) != 0 )
      echo '<td colspan="' . $colspan . '">&nbsp;</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
  }

  echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: actually i don't want to disply indexed value at the end of each row. if indexed value arrived at the end of row, the value before the indexed value must be pushed at the end like. `1 2 3 5 6 4`

Comment: @jeni - What exactly do you mean by "indexed"?

Comment: "m"=>"5","s"=>"6" indexed value

Comment: @jeni - So as you loop through the array, you want to check if the next value has a non-numeric key and if so insert it first?

Comment: @jeni - What should happen if there are more "indexed" values than columns?

Comment: am indexing only two values as non numeric not more than two. so this won't be problem i think

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1279/discussion-between-jeni-and-francois-deschenes)